Unprecise fabric defect detection
So, I am using this function to draw rectangles around the defects present in an image representing fabric (mainly denim).
Currently, there are too many false positives and the drawing is kinda around the edges, not on the defects themselves( its because am using edge detection).
This is what am currently using:
def highlight_defects(image, edges, min_contour_area=75):
    # Normalize the edge image
    edges_normalized = (edges - np.min(edges)) / (np.max(edges) - np.min(edges))

    # Apply a manually set threshold
    threshold_value = 0.32
    defect_mask = (edges_normalized > threshold_value).astype(np.uint8) * 255

    # Visualize the thresholded image
    plt.imshow(defect_mask, cmap='gray')
    plt.title('Defect Mask')
    plt.show()

    # Morphological operations to remove small noise and enhance defects
    kernel = np.ones((3, 3), np.uint8)
    defect_mask = cv2.morphologyEx(defect_mask, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)
    defect_mask = cv2.dilate(defect_mask, kernel, iterations=2)  # Dilate to enhance defects
    
    # Visualize the morphologically processed mask
    plt.imshow(defect_mask, cmap='gray')
    plt.title('Processed Defect Mask')
    plt.show()

    # Find connected components in the binary mask
    num_labels, labels, stats, centroids = cv2.connectedComponentsWithStats(defect_mask, connectivity=8)

    # Convert the original grayscale image to BGR for drawing rectangles
    highlighted_image = cv2.cvtColor((image * 255).astype(np.uint8), cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)

    # Draw rectangles around the detected connected components if they are large enough
    for i in range(1, num_labels):  # Skip the background label (0)
        if stats[i, cv2.CC_STAT_AREA] > min_contour_area:
            x, y, w, h = stats[i, cv2.CC_STAT_LEFT], stats[i, cv2.CC_STAT_TOP], stats[i, cv2.CC_STAT_WIDTH], stats[i, cv2.CC_STAT_HEIGHT]
            cv2.rectangle(highlighted_image, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 0, 255), 2)

    return highlighted_image

if there are any suggestions to make it more precise or change it to something better, I would appreciate it.
I tried using other method such as LBP or contour detection, but I find it hard to configure or work.
Also, changing the threshold doesn't effect the result that much.

you could use deep learning. that's state-of-the-art. or you could engineer some program to be sensitive to the difference between defects and intact fabric. I'd recommend the former. it turns the problem into a training problem. -- maybe give us the data on which your code fails. [mre] implies data to run the code on.

thats the problem, data . at first i was going to do that but due to different circumstances , i don't have enough data for defects . all i got are around 100 non defective images. which is why i made a one class svm classifier to detect whether the image has an anomaly or not than proceeded to make that function to highlight them .

that's a common "issue", which is why defect detection relies on capturing the normal appearance of something, and flagging anything abnormal. you'd only need training data for intact fabric.
